# Looking for a responsive XML editor written for the web-browser

Tags: open-source, javascript, web-browser, xml, json

I am looking for a responsive open-source XML editor that is capable of generating data from a schema and validating instances against schemas.

I really like this JSON editor which does the job particularly well for JSON: https://github.com/jdorn/json-editor

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean a stand-alone Web app, a browser extension, or a (JavaScript-based) editor for including in your site?

Comment: XMLSchema? RELAX NG? DTD?

Comment: JavaScript-based ideally, but I'd also like to look at other solutions if you know of any. Yeah exactly, DTD, XSD, etc.